# jquery show hide error in php

Tags: php, jquery

I have a div on the left side with links and on the right a div containing the text. Clicking on the links should change the text. And the code below works fine when its a .html page but when i rename it to .php It dosent work!!!

code in index.php

```
<ul class="blocks-holder">
            <li class="block-1">
                <ul id="sidebar">
                    <li class="sidemenu">
                        <h2 class="custom"><span>О Аикидоу</span></h2>      
                        <ul>
                            <li class="cat-item"><a href="#" id="aikido" class="oaikidou">Аикидо</a></li>
                            <li class="cat-item"><a href="#" id="cemu" class="oaikidou">Чему служи?</a></li>
                            <li class="cat-item"><a href="#" id="odlike" class="oaikidou">Одлике тренинга</a></li>
                            <li class="cat-item"><a href="#" id="druga" class="oaikidou">Друга страна катане</a></li>
                            <li class="cat-item"><a href="#" id="istorija"  class="oaikidou">Историјат</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>   
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="block-2">
                <div id="aikido">
                    <p class="block-title custom">Аикидо</p>
                    <br/>
                    <p class="thumb-text">
                        Употребна вредност једне борилачке вештине не може се измерити у рингу, 
                        па чак ни на улицу у конфликтој ситуацији која ће вам се можда догодити пар пута у животу или
                        вам се ако имате среће неће догододити уопште. Квалитет вештине мери се у свакодневном животу, 
                        кроз пролазне фазе расположења и свакодневне ритуале у периоду од јутра до мрака. 
                        Упpаво по томе се аикидо разликује од осталих борилачких вештина. 
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div id="cemu" style="display:none">
                    <p class="block-title custom">Чему служи?</p>
                    <br/>
                    <p class="thumb-text">
                        Аикидо вас спрема за савакодневни живот имајући у виду да није увек весео и здрав. 
                        Тајна је у традиционалном приступу борењу и идеји да живот постоји и након педесете године 
                        старости и да може бити подједнако забаван. Многи ударачки спортови и вештине своју примењивост 
                        заснивају на снази и физичкој спремности практиканата, што је легитиман приступ уколико је борца 
                        висок два метра и тежак 130 кг мишић, а пре пар дана је изашао из пубертета. Ипак, поставља се 
                        питање да ли је таквом борцу самодбрана уопште и потребна? Специфичност Аикидоа управо лежи у 
                        томе што је подређен аикидисти и његовим могућностима. Одређено бацање или хват више одгаварају 
                        нижим људима, док ће виши и тежи противници радије примењивати фронталне и директније нападе. 
                        Једноставно речено Аикидо је вештина за свакога невезано за године и занимање. 
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div id="odlike" style="display:none">
                    <p class="block-title custom">Одлике тренинга</p>
                    <br/>
                    <p class="thumb-text">
                        Један део тренинга у Аикидо клубу “Кошава” састоји се од низа вежби које ће подићи вашу кондицију на завидан ниво, 
                        док је онај главни остављен за репетицију ситних покрета који формирају једну одбрамбену  технику. 
                        Јер Аикидо је пре свега вештина самоодбране. Дужим практиковањем стећи ћете дијагоналну перспективу на свет 
                        коју вам омогућује новостечена снага коју сте добили тренингом, али ћете захваљујући филозофији Аикидоа бити 
                        свесни одговорности коју таква улога пружа, јер без етике нема ни моћи. Аикидо пре свега служи да вам олакша живот, 
                        да вам седење у канцеларији не представља проблем, да шетање пса не буде мучење и за њега и за вас, да се осечате као 
                        тинејџер који је случајно набасао на мудрост, тражећи нешто сасвим друго. Ова вештина је одличан начин испољите 
                        негативну енергију кроз агресију у идеалном окружењу и на људима који ће вам на томе бити захвални и узвратити истом мером. 
                        Аикидо није такмичење, у њему није идеја да стигнете први на циљ, већ да доласку на циљи не заборавите путовање до њега. 
                        Ипак Аикидо има и другу страну медаље, тупу и оштру страну катане. 
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div id="druga" style="display:none">
                    <p class="block-title custom">Друга страна катане</p>
                    <br/>
                    <p class="thumb-text">
                        Филозофски приступ је добар у сали, али је примена значајнији адут на улици. 
                        Аикидо обувата све аспекте борења, ударце кобинује са хватовима и бацањима, а полуга у корену зауставља сваки злонамерни напад. 
                        У зависности од примене и силе употребљене у техници Аикидо може да повреди, онесвести а чак и да нападачу одузме живот. 
                        Управо због озбиљности ове вештине тренер мора да буде особа од поверења са интегритетом и неопходним искуством у борењу и животу. 

                    </p>
                </div>
                <div id="istorija" style="display:none">
                    <p class="block-title custom">Историја вештине</p>
                    <br/>
                    <p class="thumb-text">
                          Јапанска борилачка вештина, релативно новог порекла, узела је маха у целокупном свету. 
                        Без обзира на своју кратку историју, она своје корене вуче из великог културног и историјског наслеђа, 
                        најстаријих борилачких вештина и старе источне традиције. Своје име Аикидо дугује комбинацији три идеограма : 
                        АИ- овај идеограм означава хармонију, општи склад у универзуму, КИ- буквални превод би био „пра-енергија“, 
                        односи се на унутрашњу енергију која води наше тело кроз стазе живота, „КИ“ има веома велику улогу у животу просечног Јапанца, 
                        јер пре модерне медицине све болести, источни лекари лечили су преко те, необјашњиве силе, 
                        ДО- означава одређени пут, правац у којем се наша животна прича развија, овај пут је усклађен хармонијом и енергијом раније поменутом.  
                        Оснивач ове борилачке дисциплине јесте Морихеј Уешиба (1883-1969). „О сенсеи“ (врховни мајстор, први учитељ) 
                        технике аикидоа узео је из аикиђуцуа који је научио од свог учитеља Сокаку Такеде, као и из : ђиу-ђицуа, кендђуцуа итд. 
                        Склад свих ових борилачких стилова обогаћен је сопственим техникама највећег мајстора, у изванредан, примењив и визуелно елегантан борилачки склоп. 
                    </p>
                </div>
            </li>               
        </ul>
```

the jquery function

```
$(".oaikidou").click(function () {
        var divname= this.id;
          $("#"+divname+"").show("slow").siblings().hide("slow");
        }); 
$('.oaikidou').click(function(e){
              e.preventDefault();
              $("#").load($(this).attr('href'));
        });
```

Comment: The final page you see in your browser **is** just an HMTL page. This should have no effect on your javascript. Can you show us exactly where your script is sitting on your page?

Comment: Can you elaborate "it doesn't work"?

Comment: I'm assuming he means the code isn't showing/hiding. Changing to the .php extension shouldn't have any effect on your code (since it contains NO PHP code whatsoever). The only problem I would think would occur is that the PHP parser is more strict with JS. Have you tried Inspecting Element (right-click, inspect element) and checking the console to see if there is a Javascript error somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

First, I don't know why you're binding 2 click handlers to handle the same click. Merge that into a single handler.

Second, you have a typo in your second click handler `$("#").load($(this).attr('href'));` You're missing the actual `divname` ID.

My corrections (personally, I would clean this up even further but I'll leave that as an exercise for you).

```
$(function(){
        $('.oaikidou').click(function(e){
                var divname= this.id;
                $("#"+divname).show("slow").siblings().hide("slow");
                $("#"+divname).load($(this).attr('href'));
                e.preventDefault();
        });
});
```

Comment: Ty, I have no idea what i did just now but because of deleting a twitter.js i got that problem,,I returned it now and it works. The second function is for the page not to return top after clicking a link.you can check it out on www.aikido-kosava.rs/site, im still making it..Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

I solved my particular problem. It wasn't because i renamed my page from html->php, along the way i removed a jquery library twitter.js, that was used in a drop down box:

```
<div id="top">
  <div class="box">
  //// so i removed this part (to put in a login form)
  //    <div id="latest-tweet"><img src="img/twitter.png" class="twitter-bird"   
  //  alt="Twitter" /></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and the first code stopped working...
Probably tweater.js is used on the box or top divs, but have no idea why
Here's my site (till tomorow): www.aikido-kosava.rs/site
But it will be: www.aikido-kosava.rs
Ty to all